# Splitting integer for two parts

Tags: c#, math, integer

I need to split an integer for two parts - the last digit and everything else.

The integer can be from 2-digit to 4-digit.

What is the fastest and safest(type wise) way to do that?

```
Function(20) >>> int1 = 2; int2 = 0;
Function(763) >>> int1 = 76; int2 = 3;
Function(800) >>> int1= 80; int2 = 0;
Function(1115) >>> int1 = 111; int2 = 5;
```

Comment: What have you tried? (hint modulo)

Comment: It's not clear what kind of problem you have with your current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that returns an array with the two desired elements like this:

```
public static int[] function(int number)
{
    int[] res = new int[2];
    res[0] = number / 10;
    res[1] = number % 10;
    return res;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: What will happen when I call the method like this: `function(5);`

Comment: function(5) returns an array with this values : [0, 5]

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a quick research about modulo operator as Gilad Green hinter, I came with a solution myself:

```
int Value = 763;
int First = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Truncate((double) Value / 10));
int Second = Convert.ToInt16((double) Value % 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

To split one of aproach is

```
Function(toSplit)
...
    int dozens= toSplit / 10; //(get dozens values)
    int singular = a % 10; //get remaining value, of singular value
```

Comment: It seems more appropriate to explain your solution, rather than criticize the alleged simplicity of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have define the method like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4nOwQg):

```
public static int[] SplitMyInteger(int inputInteger)
{
   int[] result=new int[2];
   if(inputInteger>10)
   {
       result[0]=inputInteger%10;
       result[1]=inputInteger/10;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Which will give you an integer array having last digit in 0th index and the remaining part in 1st index, if the number is less than `10`(not having 2 digit) both the results will be `0`; you can call the method like this:

```
var result = SplitMyInteger(4);
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",result[0],result[1]);
// prints 0,0
var result = SplitMyInteger(452);
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",result[0],result[1]);
// prints 2,45
```